# Cal $2$ $p$-series convergent vs divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am having difficulties understanding how an infinite $p$-series converges vs diverges.

The infinite sum of $\frac{1}{n^p}$, if $p>1$ then convergent and if $p\leq1$ then divergent.

I understand that if $p=3$ that $\frac{1}{n^p}$ will eventually converge because as more terms are calculated the quantity of them diminishes so that eventually you add almost nothing.

However I'm having trouble understanding the case where $p\leq 1$ where it diverges.

For example when $p=1$ the terms are: $1 + 0.5 + 0.333 + 0.25 + \ldots$

While I do see that the summation is growing, the rate at which it is growing is decreasing. But apparently it sums up to infinity hence why it's divergent. I would think that eventually its growth would be so insignificant that it would converge.

Comment: "will eventually converge" is a strange concept.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know how to evaluate improper integrals, intuitively, [we can compare this to an integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence):

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^p}\sim\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^p}~\mathrm dx$$

---

When $p=1$, we get

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k\sim\int_1^\infty\frac1x~\mathrm dx=\ln(x)\bigg|_1^\infty=\infty$$

So it diverges.

(Note that $\ln(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$)

---

When $p>1$, we get

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^p}\sim\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^p}~\mathrm dx=-\frac1{(p-1)x^{p-1}}\bigg|_1^\infty=\frac1{p-1}<\infty$$

So it converges.

(Note that $1/x^{p-1}\to0$ as $x\to\infty$)

---

When $p<1$, we get

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^p}\sim\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^p}~\mathrm dx=-\frac1{(p-1)x^{p-1}}\bigg|_1^\infty=\infty$$

So it diverges.

(Note that $1/x^{p-1}\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$)

Answer (score 0):

This is a VERY commonly asked question and there are a lot of resources to help you understand why online. Search for harmonic series proof. This will explain why the series diverges at p = 1. And if it diverges when p = 1 it clearly diverges for p = .999 or whatever else because all terms will be bigger.

Proof from an educator: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus-home/series-calc/convergence-divergence-tests-calc/v/harmonic-series-divergent

Further discussion of series and proof: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)

Answer (score 0):

The most intuitive, simple way I have seen to explain why the harmonic series (this series, $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\ldots$ is so important it has a name) diverges goes something like this

We're going to split the sum into an infinite number of finite sums where the k$^{th}$ finite sum has $2^k$ terms.

$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+\ldots=\\
1+\frac{1}{2}+(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4})+(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8})+\ldots >\\
1 + \frac{1}{2} +(2*\frac{1}{4}) + (4*\frac{1}{8})\ldots=
1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\ldots\\$$
And that last one clearly diverges

If you want to be a bit more rigorous about this argument, you could use some proof by contradiction. Suppose this sum has a bound called M. Since each list of $2^k$ terms in the sum add another $\frac{1}{2}$, it would take 2M of these summed together to be greater than M. So after $\Sigma_{k=1}^{2M}\ 2^k$ terms, this sum will be bigger than the supposed bound. A closed from of this sum is $2^{(2M)+1}-2$ not that you need a closed form for this proof to be valid, but now we can do some calculations with it.

Suppose you wanted enough terms so that the sum is bigger than 100. $M=100$, so by having $2^{2*100+1}-2 = 2^{201}-2$ terms, we guarantee the sum will be at least 100. Plugging the sum $\Sigma_{k=1}^{2^{201}-2} \frac{1}{k}$ into [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%201%20to%202%5E(201)%20of%201%2Fn), we get $139.8$ (I rounded down since we wanted this number to be greater than another number). So we can calculate an upper bound on the number of terms required to make the harmonic series bigger than any given number, even though our estimate on the number of terms rises exponentially.

Comment: Might want to mention the Cauchy condensation test.